# How to create a form that flys out onto the screen using javascript/css

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I am relatively new to web programming (not programming, but yes to web). I am trying to figure out how to build a form that is off screen then when clicked, it moves onto the screen to allow the user to fill in some fields and submit the form field data. I found a good example of what I'd like to do on pcmag.com.
They have a 'subscribe' link on the right side of the screen, then when you click it the form moves onto the screen from off the screen to be filled in and submitted.

I'd have posted images, but as this is my first post here, it looks like I'm not allowed to.

Thanks for any pointers/direction.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking of a modal. Use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html) as a UI framework and this will be a ton easier for you.

Comment: Thanks again aspencer8111, I like the look of what can be done with the framework, I shall try to figure it out. cheers

Answer (score 1):

You use window.open("http://www.myform.com");

You can specifiy the location of the new window too.

[Full list of values here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)